# Linear equation over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, congruences

For given $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is there a criterion which allows one to determine whether there exists $x\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ with $ax=b$?

Comment: A sufficient condition would be if $a$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but this is not a necessary condition for if $b=0$, then $ax=b$ always has a solution regardless of whether $a$ is invertible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a solution if and only if the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $n$ is a factor of $b$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You want to see whether there exist $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
ax+ny=b
$$
(using for $a$ and $b$ representatives of the given elements in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$).

What does Bézout's theorem say?

Hint: consider the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $n$.